# while implementing adjacency list, is the 1D vector automatically getting converted into 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, adjacency-list

beginner here, I was **implementing an adjacency list** to represent the graph in C++, I was stuck conceptually in the below code snippet.

```
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int s, int d) {
  adj[s].push_back(d);
  adj[d].push_back(s);
}
```

`vector<int> adj[]` will contain list of all nodes
My question is we have 1D vector adj[], **how are we able to push multiple elements within the single-cell / index** of adj[], wouldn't that require a 2D vector like `vector<vector<int>> adj[];`

By pushing multiple elements I want to clarify, the adjacent vertices for that particular node will get pushed in that particular index

The entire code::

```
// Adjacency List representation in C++

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Add edge
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int s, int d) {
  adj[s].push_back(d);
  adj[d].push_back(s);
}

// Print the graph
void printGraph(vector<int> adj[], int V) {
  for (int d = 0; d < V; ++d) {
    cout << "\n Vertex "
       << d << ":";
    for (auto x : adj[d])
      cout << "-> " << x;

    printf("\n");
    cout << "\nsize=" << adj[d].size()<<"\n";
  }
}

int main() {

  int V = 5;

  // Create a graph
  vector<int> adj[V];

  // Add edges
  addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
  addEdge(adj, 0, 2);
  addEdge(adj, 0, 3);
  addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
  printGraph(adj, V);

  cout << "\n\nmatrix cell"
       << adj[0][2];
}
```

output:

```
 Vertex 0:-> 1-> 2-> 3

size=3

 Vertex 1:-> 0-> 2    

size=2

 Vertex 2:-> 0-> 1    

size=2

 Vertex 3:-> 0

size=1

 Vertex 4:

size=0
```

Comment: `vector<int> adj[]` is an array of vectors, so it's 2D.  Albeit using two different mechanisms.

Comment: if you wrote that code, why did you make `adj` an array of vectors? If you didnt write the code, where did you get it from?

Comment: Most likely you want to have `vector<vector<int>> adj;` for your adjacency list.

Comment: please give proper reference when you post code written by someone else.

Comment: the code you are using is relying on non standard compiler extension ([Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)). Its not recommended to learn C++ from random code you find online.

Comment: @Eijay Thank you for commenting on the exact term, I didn't know about the array of vectors